# Mongoose Node API in an existing DB not returning results and shows no errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I'm new to APIs based on nodeJS and I would like to connect to an already existing collection in a MongoDB database. 
If I try to access `http://localhost:8080/teams` I get an error on the browser: Cannot GET /Teams.
Not even the `console.log` get printed but nodemon (that I'm using to load after each save) shows no errors.

This is an example of the existing records:

```
use MYDB
db.TeamsCol.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d702df59ba60607dad06df4"), "teamID" : 1, "teamName" : "PT", "datetime" : "04-09-2019 10:21:16 Wednesday" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d702ed59ba60607dad06df5"), "teamID" : 2, "teamName" : "ES", "datetime" : "01-09-2019 11:20:00 Sunday" }
```

I built the following struture:

```
project folder: API

API/server.js 
API/models/teamModel.js
API/Routes/teamRouter.js
```

as described below:

API/server.js file:

```
// Import express
let express = require('express');
// Import Body parser
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// Import Mongoose
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Initialise the app
let app = express();

// Setup server port
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Import routes
let apiRouter = require("./Routes/teamRouter");

// Connecting to the database
const db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/MYDB', {useNewUrlParser: true});

// setting body parser middleware 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// API routes
app.use('/Teams', apiRouter);

// Running the server
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

API/models/teamModel.js file:

```
// Import Mongoose
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const teamModel = new Schema({
    teamID: { type: Number   },
    teamName: { type: String },
    datetime: { type: String },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('teamsModel', teamModel, 'TeamsCol');
```

API/Routes/teamRouter.js file:

```
// Import express
let express = require('express');
// Import Teams controller
var Team = require('../models/teamModel');

const teamRouter = express.Router();

teamRouter.route('/teams')
.get((req, res) => {
    Console.log(req)
    Team.find({}, (err, teams) => {
        res.json(teams)
    })  
})

// Middleware 
teamRouter.use('/:team', (req, res, next)=>{
Team.findById( req.params.team, (err,team)=>{
    if(err)
        res.status(500).send(err)
    else {
        req.team = team;
        next()
    }
})

})
teamRouter.route('/:team')
.get((req, res) => {
    res.json(req.team)
}) // end get Teams/:team 

// Export API routes
module.exports = teamRouter;
```

Here are the versions I'm using

```
mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3

node --version
v8.9.4
```

and also the package.json contents:

```
{
"name": "teamsapi",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "server.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"mongoose": "^5.6.12"
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your `server.js` file, you already used:

```
app.use('/Teams', apiRouter);
```

So the api `/teams` doesn't exist, it should be `/Teams/teams`. And the full url will be `http://localhost:8080/Teams/teams`.